# unable to parse ints with antlr

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse ints, but I can parse only multi-digit ints, not single-digit ints.

I narrowed it down to a very small lexer and parser which I based on sample grammars from antlr.org as follows:

```
# IntLexerTest.g4
lexer grammar IntLexerTest;

DIGIT
    : '0' .. '9'
    ;

INT
   : DIGIT+
   ;


#IntParserTest.g4
parser grammar IntParserTest;
options {
    tokenVocab = IntLexerTest;
}

mything
    : INT
    ;
```

And when I try to parse the digit 3 all by itself, I get "line 1:0 mismatched input '3' expecting INT". On the other hand, if I try to parse 33, it's fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had the same issue and did not get to the bottom of it.  Ended up defining rules for single-digit INT and multi-digit INT separately.  Can't be right but it's all I could do to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lexer matches rules from top to bottom. When 2 (or more) rules match the same amount of characters, the rule defined first will win. That is why a single digit is matched as an `DIGIT` and two or more digits as an `INT`.

What you should do is make `DIGIT` a `fragment`. Fragments are only used by other lexer rules and will never become a token of their own:

```
fragment DIGIT
 : '0' .. '9'
 ;

INT
 : DIGIT+
 ;
```

Comment: Little addition: never use fragments in parser rules. ANTLR allows that but the outcome is not what you expect.